# MongoDB Lookup Issue

Tags: mongodb

In collection A, we have

```json
"batches" : [
    ObjectId("56fccffbe7c9f9cf7634dbfe")
],
```

and in Collection B, we have

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56fccffbe7c9f9cf7634dbfe") }
```

Can we perform a lookup between these 2 collections?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [$lookup operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) as part of an aggregation, after you [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the batches array. For example:

```js
db.collectionA.aggregate[

  { $unwind: "$batches" },

  { $lookup:
    from: "collectionB",
    localField: "batches",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "collectionB"
  }
]
```